# Split a list into two in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Im trying to split a list into 2 in prolog. But im still new to this and any help would be much appreciated.

My problem is:

Implement a clause choose(N,L,R,S) that chooses N items from L and puts them in R with the remaining elements in L left in S

This is what i have tried so far:

```
split(0,_L1,_L2,_L4). 
split(X,[H|T],L1,T):-
     X>0,
     X1 is X-1,
     split(X1,T,[H|L1],T).
```

When i try to run

```
split(2,[1,2,4,5],X,Y).
false
```

This is the result i get. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If X > 0, the first element of the `L` list must also be the first element of the `R` list. For example, this should hold: `split(1, [a | Rest], [a], Rest)`. If we want this relationship to hold, we must express it in the *head* of a rule.

Your second clause should therefore look more like this:

```
split(X, [H|T], [H|L1], Rest) :-
     X > 0,
     X1 is X - 1,
     split(X1, T, L1, Rest).
```

This splits off the prefix all right, but the rest is not right yet:

```
?- split(2, [1, 2, 4, 5], R, S).
R = [1, 2|S] ;
false.
```

You need to think again about the case where 0 elements are to be split off. What should be the result of `split(0, [a, b, c], R, S)`?

Answer (score 0):

You biggest problem is the way in which you are constructing/deconstructing the 3rd argument.

And you're missing a special case.

Most recursive problems has a couple of special, usually terminating, cases and one general case. This problem has two special cases.

The general case is simple. You'll note here that we unify the third argument with `[X|Pfx]`. This adds `X` to the head of the left/prefix result, and gives us its (likely unbound) tail. That tail gets passed down in recursion.

```
partition( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Pfx] , Sfx ) :-
    N > 0 ,
    N1 is N-1 ,
    partition( N1, Xs, Pfx, Sfx )
    .
```

[You might notice that we're building a list in the 3rd argument (the prefix list) as we go along... but it's not a legal list: the tail is presumably unbound. We'll take care of that at the end.

So...that takes care of the general case. But, how do we know when we're done?

One special/terminating case is when the source list is exhausted. If that happens before `N` decrements to `0`, we're done. We can handle that like this:

```
partition( _ , [], [], [] ).
```

We don't really care what the value of `N` is, but it might be useful to enfoce the constraint that `N >= 0`. What's happening here is that when the source list (the 2nd argument) is exhausted and is empty list, we (1) close the prefix list (3rd argument) and unify the suffix list with the empty list.

The next special case is when `N` is finally decremented to zero. That's no more complex:

```
partition( 0 , Sfx, [], Sfx ).
```

We unify whatever is left of the source list with the suffix list (4th argument) and close the prefix list with the empty list.

The remaining special case is when `N` is finally decremented to `0`. That's just as simple. Here's:

```
partition( 0 , Xs, [], Xs ).
```

Put it all together and you get:

```
partition( _ , []     , []      , []  ).
partition( 0 , Sfx    , []      , Sfx ).
partition( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Pfx] , Sfx ) :-
  N > 0 ,
  N1 is N-1,
  partition( N1, Xs , Pfx , Sfx ).
```